# Fitting Powerlaw exponential to the data matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have two sets of data: y and x. For exampe

```
y=[5,4,2,1,3,4,...];
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,...];
```

I want to fit them below functions and find coefficients a,b,c,a0,b0,c0,a1,b1 and c1.
How can I do that?
Functions are:

```
y= a x^b exp(-x/c)
```

and:

```
y= a0 x^b0 exp(-x/c0)+ a1 x^b1 exp(-x/c1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo_fit = fittype('a*x^b*exp(-x/c)',...
                  'dependent',{'y'},'independent',{'x'},...
                  'coefficients',{'a','b','c'});
res = fit(x',y',foo_fit);
```

You can also specify a recursive `n` as the `problem` parameter in `fittype` (so you don't have to explicitly state each coefficient (c0,c1,...,cn)) but I'm not sure how/if this is possible

Comment: Important note: this requires the Curve Fitting Toolbox.  Other toolboxes can also perform a regression of this type, but none make it this easy.

Comment: It give warning: Warning: Start point not provided, choosing random start point.

Comment: You can specify `StartPoint`, `Lower`/`Upper` limits, etc.  as properties in the `fit()` function (https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html#namevaluepairarguments)

Comment: `fit(x',y' foo_fit, StartPoint, [0,0,0])`

Comment: Using StartPoint, [0,0,0], doesn't change the answer? how can I know that what should I replace for startpoint?

Comment: Start point should not matter for the end result because this type of regression should always be able to find global maxima